# How to search an item in specific folder in one drive?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am using Microsoft Graph to manipulate files in OneDrive. I need to search for a file in a specific folder, and if the file exists, delete that file.

I am using the following code to search file, it gives the search results for the whole drive.

```
var checkIfExists = this.graphClient
 .Me
 .Drive
 .Search(item["FileName"].ToString())
 .Request()
 .GetAsync()
 .Result;
```

I need to search file in specific folder only for example in duplicate folder only.

Comment: Do you actually need to search a specific folder (and all it's sub-folders), or do you just need to know if a file with a specific name is a child of a specific folder? Search might be overkill

Comment: I actually need to search within the folder for the file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can scope the search to any path you like. For example, using the default [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#) dataset, we can search for `finance` across the entire Drive using this query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='finance')?select=name,id,webUrl
```

If we would prefer to only search under a single subfolder (for example `/CR-227 Project/`), then we can use that Path as the starting point:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/CR-227 Project:/search(q='finance')?select=name,id,webUrl
```

Additionally, if we know the `DriveItem.Id` for `/CR-227 Project/` (`01BYE5RZ6TAJHXA5GMWZB2HDLD7SNEXFFU`), then we could use that Id instead of the Path:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/01BYE5RZ6TAJHXA5GMWZB2HDLD7SNEXFFU/search(q='finance')?select=name,id,webUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

As Drive is the top level resource that represents a user's one drive, it has relationships to other items that are known as DriveItems. A drive item can be anything, a file, folder, or any other item stored in the drive.

So, to search for a specific file inside the drive you could make a request;

```
var driveItems = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root
.Search(<'{search-query}'>)
.Request()
.GetAsync();
```

This should help you get the DriveItem based on your search query, once you've retrieved the DriveItem, you can make a request for deleting it based on the id of the item;

```
await graphClient.Me.Drive
.Items[<"{item-id}">]
.Request()
.DeleteAsync();
```

Update:

As per the request for the help with the code for finding the file and deleting it, I've given it below for your reference.

```
var files = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root
.Search("abc.pdf")
.Request()
.GetAsync();

var duplicateFile = files
.Where(driveItem => driveItem.ParentReference.Name
.ToLower() == "duplicate")
    .FirstOrDefault();

if(duplicateFile != null) {
await graphClient.Me.Drive
.Items[duplicateFile.Id]
.Request()
.DeleteAsync();
}
```

Comment: The search query you suggested gives search collection pages and if the file exist in more than one folder it returns all result, this becomes difficult to find the file to be deleted.

Comment: I hope you're using the correct search query? The one I have put in my code snippet is a placeholder.

Comment: I am new to graph api, could you please suggest the search query. Let file named 'abc.pdf' to be search in folder duplicate. The file 'abc.pdf' also reside in another folder attachment. I don't want to include search result from attachment folder.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the code snippet. Hope that helps.

Comment: Where condition throwing exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. driveItem.ParentReference.Name returns null every time whether match is found or not.

Comment: @ShyamNarayan Do you know the exact path of the file where you expect it to be in case of a duplicate?