# Recursively expanding children in OneDrive graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, onedrive

I would like to get all the contents of a folder in OneDrive. The folder has child folders within it, and child folders within them, e.g.:

```
Parent/
└── Child1/
    ├── Child1.1/
    │   ├── File1.1.1
    │   └── File1.1.2
    └── Child1.2/
        ├── File1.2.1
        └── File1.2.2
```

I would like to maintain knowledge about folder hierarchy, basically something like `Parent/Child1/File1.1.1` so I can't use the empty query graph search approach referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60440298/microsoft-graph-list-children-including-grandchildren), which returns everything in a flat format without any information about the hierarchy.

I could recursively call each folder one by one but that would be a lot since there are thousands of folders in the parent directory.

Based on the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/optional-query-parameters?view=odsp-graph-online#optional-odata-query-parameters) (and [here too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters)), I would have expected the `expand=children` parameter to work, but it seems not to. Any ideas?

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/<id>/children?$expand=children
{
  "error": {
    "code": "notSupported",
    "message": "Operation not supported",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2022-12-17T17:03:28",
      "request-id": "",
      "client-request-id": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60440298/microsoft-graph-list-children-including-grandchildren but still without solution

Answer (score 0):

Use this url to get children listing, I have pasted the link below.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/<id>?expand=children
```