# Is it possible to search for files within a directory in OneDrive using the Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

The official Graph API documentation states that it is possible to:

```
search within a folder hierarchy
```

However, the entire drive is searched when we perform a folder scoped search like the following:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Folder:/search(q='file')?select=name,webUrl,driveId
```

This has been discussed here [2] but either this has changed in the last year or did not work in the first place.

Is this a bug or intended behaviour? Can we scope the search to a single directory?

Reference

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
[2] [How to search an item in specific folder in one drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56302835/how-to-search-an-item-in-specific-folder-in-one-drive)